# Extend spring data's default syntax

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

In my current project almost every entity has a field `recordStatus` which can have 2 values:

- `A` for Active
- `D` for Deleted

In spring data one can normally use:

```
repository.findByLastName(lastName)
```

but with the current data model we have to remember about the active part in every repository call, eg.

```
repository.findByLastNameAndRecordStatus(lastName, A)
```

The question is: is there any way to extend spring data in such a way it would be able to recognize the following method:

```
repository.findActiveByLastName(lastName)
```

and append the

```
recordStatus = 'A'
```

automatically?

Comment: Assuming you are using hibernate use a default `@Where` on your entity or use hibernate filters.

Comment: this sounds like a good idea, but it will make the solution not extendable, it will not allow us to introduce new statuses easily

Comment: The solution would be even more flexible then what you have. Your solution would need to have modifications to the integration code. Hibernate filters can be configured with placeholders. (I strongly suggest a read of the hibernate reference guide).

Comment: Good point, it looks like a step in the right direction

Comment: Currently your best bet is `@Where` other than that this is a know issue and spring team is working on it according to this jira: [Add support for soft deletes](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-307)

Comment: Here what I found : http://jeroenbellen.ghost.io/spring-data-extending-the-jpa-specification-executor/

It's is not exactly the same thing, but it looks like the method can make you achieve what you want.

Let us know your solution if you ever find one ;)

Comment: An other solution would be to switch your recordStatus to a boolean since findActiveTrueByLastName or findActiveFalseByLastName is valid (if possible, but according to what you said, you have only 2 values, so true/false would work in that case).

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data JPA provides 2 additional options for you dealing with circumstances that their DSL can't handle by default.

The first solution is custom queries with an @Query annotation

```
@Query("select s from MyTable s where s.recordStatus like 'A%'")
public MyObect findActiveByLastName(String lastName);
```

The second solution is to add a completely custom method the "Old Fashion Way" You can create a new class setup like: MyRepository**Impl** The Impl is important as it is How spring knows to find your new method (Note: you can avoid this, but you will have to manually link things the docs can help you with that)

```
//Implementation
public class MyRepositoryImpl implements MyCustomMethodInterface {
   @PersistenceContext
   EntityManager em;

    public Object myCustomJPAMethod() {
       //TODO custom JPA work similar to this
       String myQuery = "TODO";
       return em.createQuery(myQuery).execute();
    }
}

//Interface
public interface MyCustomMethodInterface {
    public Object myCustomJPAMethod();
}

//For clarity update your JPA repository as well so people see your custom work
public interface MySuperEpicRepository extends JPARepository<Object, String>, MyCustomMethodInterface {

}
```

These are just some quick samples so feel free to go read their Spring Data JPA docs if you would like to get a bit more custom with it.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Finally just a quick note.  Technically this isn't a built in feature from Spring Data JPA, but you can also use Predicates.  I will link you to a blog on this one since I am not overly familiar on this approach.
https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Data's `Specifications`. Take a look at [this](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) article.

If you create a 'Base'-specification with the recordStatus filter, and deriving all other specifications form this one.

Of course, everybody in your team should use the specifactions api, and not the default spring data api.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can extend the syntax unless you override the base class (`SimpleReactiveMongoRepository`; this is for reactive mongo but you can find the class for your DB type), what I can suggest you is to extend the base methods and then make your method be aware of what condition you want to execute. If you check this post you get the idea that I did for the patch operation for all entities.

https://medium.com/@ghahremani/extending-default-spring-data-repository-methods-patch-example-a23c07c35bf9